# How to Replace Action Bar's Text with multiple buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

**I have something like this in my app:**

[image]

**How do I replace the text with buttons so it looks something like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Remove your action bar.
Add below code in your manifest application tag

```
<android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

2. Use tab layout.
   For more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html
   Example of tab layout:
   http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

You can take custom toolbar and put all the images in toolbar, This is best way like following.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Set Activity theme as `AppTheme.NoActionBar` theme like

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

and then after dynamicaly set Toolbar in activity and access all the Image like button.

And one another way is take TabLayout for this.